# how to select using condition in sql query

Tags: sql, database, join, conditional-statements

i want to create select query in sql multiple and using condition, my query like this :

```
select a.name, b.* from event a right join student b on a.id=b.id_place
```

from the query above i want to display all columns from table b, when value of a.id !=0,
how to create sql query with condition like that

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i using case  when but not work, when i using query like above only data a.id=b.id_place display, i want not a.id=b.id also display

Comment: providing sample data and expected results will improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

To add a condition to a RIGHT OUTER JOIN query, just add a WHERE clause with the desired condition. Here's an example:

```
 select a.name, b.* 
 from event a right join student b on a.id=b.id_place 
 where a.id != 0
```

Comment: but i want also select table a data

Comment: but  i want select with multiple table like my question

Comment: Then you need multiple joins.  Have you looked over any tutorials on the Internet?  There are several, and they all adequately describe how to do these things.

Comment: I have updated the answer, but it is still not clear what is your question exactly. do you want all records from table `student` or all records from `event`. what fields do you want etc.